# How to identify the default audio devices from a .Net application?

Tags: .net, windows, audio

I'm a bit confused. Is there any simple way to set proper audio devices (in/out) in my VoIP .NET application w/o using of DirectX?

"Proper audio devices" probably means - devices which are already set as DEFAULT in Windows.

E.g. Skype (or X-Lite) selects in most cases audio devices properly. But How? Just getting of list of devices don't solve the problem, cause I don't know how to select the proper one.

I suppose that solutions for XP and Vista(7) could be different.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Lazarus, thank you for answer.

I use open source voip library that in it's' turn use portaudio to manage sound devices. So i can get a list of all audio devices available in Windows. That's what I have.
The question is, how to select devices(in/out) from the list which are already set in the system as DEFAULT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Vista and Win7 you could use the MMDevice API IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint, and then use MMDevice::GetId to get the string describing this device.

On other systems (including Vista and Win7) you can use the older MME API waveInGetDevCaps and waveOutGetDevCaps using deviceID=WAVE_MAPPER (-1) to get the string describing the default device.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had to do something similar, but support multiple windows versions.  I ended up using [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) because of its simplicity.  There are several example apps bundled in so you can see how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, your solution also could be used in some cases!